# Angular 1.5 test component with jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I try test my component with Jasmine and Angular-mock, but I don't know how this do.

This is my component

```
var angular = require('angular');
'use strict';
module.exports = angular
    .module('app.login.component.login', [])
    .component('login', {
      templateUrl: '/app/js/login/components/login.template.html',
      controller: LoginController
    });

LoginController.$inject = ['$state', 'Auth', 'messages'];
function LoginController($state, Auth, messages) {
  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.failMessage = messages.NO_AUTH;
  ctrl.failResponse = false;
  ctrl.login = login;

  function login(user){
    ctrl.errors = {};
    Auth.login(user)
      .success(function(result){
        $state.go('profile');
      })
      .error(function(response) {
        ctrl.failResponse = true;
    })
  };
}
```

I write this test but his dosen't work.
 Please explain me what I do wrong and show some pattern how test component

```
describe('Component: login', function() {
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module(require('angular-ui-router')));
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module(loginComponent.name));

  var scope;
  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
  }));

   var controller;
   beforeEach(inject(function($componentController, Auth) {
     ctrl = $componentController('login', {

      $scope:scope});
   }));

   it('df', function() {
     expect(ctrl.login).toBeDefined();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You use [$componentController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$componentController).

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $componentController){
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  controller = $componentController('myComponent', {$scope: scope});
}));
```